# Stack overflow exception with Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Having a weird issue with Rails 3.2.1.  Working with a legacy database with icky column names and I'm trying to clean them up in my model.  The following model works fine in HTML, but responding with JSON or XML throws a `stack level too deep` error:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'ordersum'
    set_primary_key 'ordernbr'

    alias_attribute 'id','ordernbr'
    alias_attribute 'customer_id', 'custid'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_name', 'sname'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_company','scompany'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_address1','saddress1'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_address2','saddress2'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_city','scity'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_state','sstate'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_zip','zip'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_country','scountry'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_phone','sphone'
    alias_attribute 'shipping_method','shipvia'
    alias_attribute 'subtotal','product'
    alias_attribute 'shipping', 'freight'
    alias_attribute 'handling', 'handling'
    alias_attribute 'total', 'ordertot'
    alias_attribute 'transaction_id', 'vsTransactionId'
    alias_attribute 'reference_number', 'vsrefnbr'
    alias_attribute 'approval_code', 'vsappcode'
    alias_attribute 'created_on', 'entereddtm'
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    @orders = Order.all
    respond_with @orders
  end
end
```

Order is stack level too deep with no stack trace.

**Edit #1**  Framework/Full trace had 1 item:

`actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70`

**Edit #2**  Found some additional details after digging.  Did a rails console and an `Order.find` and got the error below.  Please note that `Order.all`works fine.

```
C:\Users\Rich\App>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> Order.find(1)
  ←[1m←[36mOrder Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `ordersum`.* FROM `ordersum` WHERE `ordersum`.`ordernbr` = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:443
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: Please show us the detailed error message with stack trace.

Comment: there wasn't a stack trace available.

Comment: Then you probably have found a bug in rails. What rails version are you using? Can you tell me how to reproduce it on my machine?

Comment: Rails 3.2.1, to reproduce, create a simple project.  Using mysql, i have a table called ordersum with the fields listed above as well as a couple others.  Please see http://pastebin.com/TdtrfinW for the complete schema.  I did not run a migration (existing schema).

Comment: This might be an issue with an installed gem. Please show your Gemfile (or upload your complete code to github) :)

Comment: gemfile was default from rails new appname -d mysql.  Nothing was added :(  The code i gave you is basically everything in the app thus far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you mean to alias `handling` to itself?

```
alias_attribute 'handling', 'handling'
```

That'll blow your stack right up.

Comment: OMG...i can't even believe i did that.  SORRY GUYS!  I must need caffeine or something!  Thanks everyone!